# devstack glance error at installation

Tags: installation, openstack, devstack, openstack-glance

```
+functions:wait_for_service:407
+lib/glance:start_glance:355
+functions-common:die:186
[Call Trace]
./stack.sh:1275:start_glance
/opt/stack/devstack/lib/glance:355:die
[ERROR] /opt/stack/devstack/lib/glance:355 g-api did not start
Error on exit
```

OS : Ubuntu 16.04

This error occurred at Controller node during OpenStack Multi-node installation.

Controller's local.conf is

```
[[local|localrc]]
HOST_IP=10.10.15.21
FLAT_INTERFACE=eth0
FIXED_RANGE=10.10.10.0/24
FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE=4096
FLOATING_RANGE=10.10.20.0/24

MULTI_HOST=1
LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD

MYSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MYSQL_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this error?

Comment: + All node in VMs.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by @M.S.Raghunandan, the following helps me start openstack:

```sh
./unstack.sh
./clean.sh
killall -u stack # kill all processes from user 'stack'
./stack.sh
```

---

Please check [openstack/devstack](https://github.com/openstack/devstack) for what those scripts do.

Answer (score 0):

This Error is Solved.

Just './unstack.sh; ./stack.sh'

Answer (score -1):

1) `./unstack.sh`

2) `./clean.sh`

3) `rm -rf devstack`

4) Reboot your system

5) `git clone <link to devstack url on git>`

6) `cd devstack`

7) `./stack.sh`